# How do I create a button that allows a user to go backwards?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**A) How do I make a Jquery Button that**

1. Add a new TextBox
2. The Id, Name, and placeholder of the TextBox, increases with each new textBox
3. and hides previous TextBox.

**B) Create another button in jquery that**

1. shows hidden textBox, and
2. hides new textbox to user unput

```js
var input,
    inputCount = 0;

function newInput() {
  inputCount++;
  if (input !== undefined) {
    input.type = "hidden";
  }


  input = document.createElement("input");
  input.type = "text";
  input.name = input.id = input.placeholder = "Entry_" + inputCount;
  document.getElementById("box").appendChild(input);
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="newInput()">Add Entry</button>
<button id="edit">Edit Previous Entry</button>
<br/>

<br/><span id="box"></span>
```

Comment: So you want one button to add a new text field and hide the previous one, and another to hide the most recent one and show the one before it?

Comment: Yes, That is exactly what I would like to do. I would like the user to be able to edit their most recent entry. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$('#box > input').show();Here is my jquery code for your requirements:

```js
var input,
  inputCount = 0;

function newInput() {
  $('#box > input').hide();
  inputCount++;
  input = $('<input>')
    .attr({
      'type': 'text',
      'placeholder': 'Entry_' + inputCount,
      'data-id': inputCount
    })
    .appendTo($('#box'));
}

function editPreviousEntry() {
  var cId = $('#box > input:visible').data('id');

  if (cId - 1 !== 0) {
    $('#box > input').hide();
    $('#box > input:nth-child(' + (cId - 1) + ')').show();
  }
  $('#box > input:nth-child(' + inputCount + ')').hide();
}
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" onclick="newInput()">Add Entry</button>
<button id="edit" onclick="editPreviousEntry()">Edit Previous Entry</button>

<br/>

<br/><span id="box"></span>
<br/>
<br/>

<!-- 
A) How do I make a Jquery Button that 
1)Add a new textBox, 
2)The Id, Name, and placeholder of the textBox, increases with each new textBox, 
3) and hides previous textBox. 

B) Create another button in jquery that 
1) shows hidden textBox, and 
2) hides new textbox to user unput 
-->
```

Comment: Thank you Amy. I would just like to be able to view the most recent entry, instead of all the entries. If you could show me how to do that, it would work perfectly.

Comment: If the user puts in several entries, I am trying to prevent from the page expanding, that is why I want only the previous entry to show, per click, if that makes any sense

Comment: thank you so much Amy, its almost there,  can you make it so that when I press the previous button, it continues? right now, it stops at just the recent one, I want the user to be able to go through all the previous entries one at a time, pressing the button. thank u in advance.

Comment: Your Code works how I want it to on here, but I can not get it to work on my wamp server, or jsfiddle.net. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am not sure why i will not work in your wamp server, but here is the link for https://jsfiddle.net/ky9pzmzb/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var box;
$(function() {
  box = $('#box');
  $('#add').on('click', addEntry);
  $('#edit').on('click', editEntry);
});

var hdn;
var cnt = 0;
var txt;

var addEntry = function(e) {
  if (hdn) {
    $('input[name=entry]').prop('type', 'hidden');
  }
  if (txt) {
    hdn = txt;
    txt.prop('type', 'text');
  }
  if (txt && !$.trim(txt.val())) {
    txt.val('').focus(); //empty text, don't hide
    return;
  }
  if (txt) {
    hdn = txt;
    hdn.prop('type', 'hidden');
  }
  txt = $('<input>');
  txt.prop({
    'type': 'text',
    'placeholder': 'Entry ' + (++cnt),
    'name': 'entry'
  });
  box.append(txt);
};

var editEntry = function(e) {
  $('input[name=entry]').prop('type', 'hidden');
  if (txt) {
    txt.prop('type', 'hidden');
  }
  if (hdn) {
    hdn.prop('type', 'text');
    if (hdn.prev(':hidden').length) {
      hdn = hdn.prev();
    }
  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id='add'>Add Entry</button>
<button type="button" id="edit">Edit Previous Entry</button>

<br/>

<br/><span id="box"></span>
<br/>
<br/>
```